# Python Reference Dictionary Key in same Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to access a key in a dictionary before "declaring" it.

Similar to this:

```
test_dict = {'path': '/root/secret/', 'path2': test_dict['path']+'meow/'}
```

I am aware that I could accomplish this by doing in the next line, like:

```
test_dict['path2'] = test_dict['path']+'meow'
```

however for readability i would prefer writing all the keys in the dict for a config file.

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: did not understand your question

Comment: Simply trying it would convince you that you cannot do it. So no. At the time `test_dict['path']` is requested, it does not exist yet.

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: Instead use:  `os.path.join(test_dict["path"],test_dict["path2"])` when you need to build the paths

Comment: You can't. In `a = b`, the right part is evaluated first, so when you are building your dict literal, `test_dict` does not exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convince yourself that this is not possible. You cannot refer to an object that hasn't even been created. What you can, however, do, is use a string variable. This should do what you want relatively easily.

```
p = '/root/secret/'
test_dict = {'path' : p, 'path2' : os.path.join(p, 'meow')}
```

Also, it's good practice to use `os.path.join` when concatenating sub-paths together.

Comment: I don't think this is readable to be honest. I would probably add the elements row-wise. Reason: you can't really import a dict with that from file.

Comment: Maybe even `p = r'/root/secret/'`

Comment: @AntonvBR Why not? I believe it's pretty clear what the code is trying to accomplish, at least more clear than OP's current attempt.

Answer (score 1):

@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I think this is more readable, imagine if OP were to add 15 paths.

```
p = '/root/secret/'

# initiate dict
test_dict = {}

# assign values
test_dict['path'] = p
test_dict['path2'] = os.path.join(p, 'meow')
```

Comment: ....uhh... then on top I'd even put `test_dict = dict()`...anyhow @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ could just format the code in two lines to achieve the same readability

Comment: @mikuszefski he could but I am giving my view of how to do this.

Comment: I mean, sure, but it really makes no difference. The point of my answer was to say it was not possible and offer a viable workaround :)